# What is the TryParseExact formatter for a JSON datetime?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, datetime, datetime-format

I'm passing a `DateTime` as a string on the wire to a Web API 2 call and I can't for the life of me figure out what formatter I need to use to get `TryParseExact` to get the precise date/time.  I'm removing the GMT offset on the client, so I need it to take the parameter as-is, without GMT.

Javascript:

```
var htmlDateString = "8/19/2015 12:00 AM";
var fromDate = new Date(htmlDateString);
//remove GMT offset
fromDate.setHours(fromDate.getHours() - (fromDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60));
var wireFormattedDate = fromDate.toJSON();  //results in 2015-08-19T00:00:00.000Z
```

Controller:

```
public string Get(string fromDate)
{
    DateTime parsedFromDate;
    if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(fromDate, "?????", CulturInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out from))
    {
        //some stuff
    }
    //some other irrelevant stuff
}
```

If I use `TryParse` (no formatter), I get the GMT offset value (I'm in GMT-6):

```
{8/18/2015 6:00:00 PM}
```

Which is not what I want.  I've tried several [formatter variations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) of the following, all of which fail to parse:

```
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:ffz
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:ffzz
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:fffz
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fffz
```

Do I need to specify a different `DateTimeStyle`?  Do I have to do anything special for the "T" and "Z" characters?  What is the format for `TryParseExact` on a JSON formatted date-time?

Comment: try the following `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'"` You can do:

```
var isParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, 
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None, 
                    out parsedFromDate);
```

Another way is to specify `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` like:

```
DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, 
                out parsedFromDate);
```

One more thing to add, personally, I have always used a specific format at Javascript end and then parse the `DateTime` in C# using the same format. I would convert the Javascript `DateTime`to a string and then pass it to the server side.